# What are the data type BulkCreate orm can accept in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

I got the API result and creating this variable `querystring`. This variable is pushing to array in loop, and final array to bulkCreate but it is failing while insertion. what kind of data type can be use for bulkCreate.

```
var queryString = col[0] + "," + col[1] + "," + col[2] + "," + col[3] + "," + col[4] + "," + col[5] + "," + col[6] + "," + col[7] + "," + col[8] + "," + col[9] + "," + col[10] + "," + col[11] + "," + col[12]+ "," + col[13]+","+col[15];
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Also you might need to check the syntax for bulkCreate, it expects an array of objects , not a query string

Comment: It adds empty rows in table , with default values described in model

Comment: It would, you are not following the syntax for bulk create